# "De janvier à février" or "de janvier en février"?

Tags: traduction, prépositions

I want to specify a time interval in months in French. I would like to say "I was working from January to February".

Should I say "Je travaille de janvier *à* février" or "Je travaille de janvier *en* février"?

Comment: « Je travaille *en* janvier et *en* février », ici, les mois se suivent.

Comment: @Personne et se ressemblent...

Comment: @jlliagre … pas autant qu'il y paraît, malgré les années bissextiles, les inuits auront toujours les pieds dans la neige moins longtemps dans le dernier !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No doubts:

> De janvier **à** février

Comment: Juste comme ça, trouve-t-on _de janvier jusqu'en février_ acceptable ?

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie: oui, c'est acceptable.

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie ou le bien rare: *de janvier jusque février*.

Comment: @jlliagre — Enjambez l'océan et *le bien [si] rare* passe à *inconnu*. :-) — « De janvier **à** février » parce que les mois se suivent, mais plutôt « De janvier à *fin* mars »,  De janvier à juillet inclus/exclu »,

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie Qu'en est-il de *de janvier jusqu'à février* ?

Comment: @jlliagre Ouais, j'ai pas trop réféchi aux nuances. Peut-être que mon premier commentaire trahit le fait que avec _jusque_ c'est très usuel, mais je sais pas si quand on parle du mois qui suit si c'est utile sans précision du genre _du début janvier jusqu'à la fin (de) février_ ça c'est bien plus usuel pour moi qu'avec la préposition _en_. Mon commentaire voulait récupérer une lecture de la question où je vois la personne penser aussi à _until_ et _into_.J'imagine que _de janvier jusque février_ m'est plutôt inconnu mais j'aime bien. En plus bien quand on prononce ça fait peu de diff. à ou e.

Comment: @jlliagre Étrangement, _de janvier à février_ me fait un peu la même impression que _de 100 à 200_ ; c'est une hésitation entre l'intervalle et l'approximation. Ou c'est le café.

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie Je me suis focalisé sur les prépositions alors que toi, c'était la proximité des mois qui te chiffonnais...